# Python way to convert categorical values into binary in the same column

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, scikit-learn

Gurus, we are looking for a pythonic way (python 2.7) to convert categorical values in a column into binary values into a single new column. Example: In the "Loan_status" column,

```
 Loan_Status
 Charged Off
 Default
 Fully Paid
 Current
 Does not meet the credit policy. Status:1
 Does not meet the credit policy. Status:0
```

We are trying to make "Charged Off", "Default" into "0", "Fully Paid", "Current" into "1", and delete any row that contains "Does not meet the credit policy. Status:1" and "Does not meet the credit policy. Status:0".

Desired Output:

```
 Loan_Status
 0
 0
 1
 1
```

Is there any pythonic way to do it?  Pandas get_dummies will generate multiple columns, so it doesn't seem to work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's define a list of positive and negative class labels.

```
positive = ['Fully Paid', 'Current']
negative = ['Charged Off', 'Default']
```

First, filter the dataframe for rows that are invalid for your model. We can use `isin` to for filtering only values in either

```
filtered_df = df[df['Loan_Status'].isin(positive + negative)].copy()
```

Second, create a new column for positive labels. If it needs to be `0` or `1` we can cast the boolean result to type `int`.

```
filtered_df['Loan_Status'] = filtered_df['Loan_Status'].isin(positive).astype(int)
```

Comment: great answer! Thank you!

Comment: Hmmm encounter a new question: if I have filtered multiple columns like this, any easy way to combine them into a big and clean table?